# Routing links in a Nav with PHP

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404, nav

I'm using PHP and XAMPP for a website. My current dilemma is that I'm not finding any answers/help on how to properly route links in my nav bar depending on which directory I am in. Here is a general file setup:

```
-index.php
|
-views folder-> nav.php, testing.php, (all php pages here)
|
-images folder-> all imgs
```

The issue is the links in my < a href="" > tags will be different for the index vs all other php pages (since they are all in my views folder).

I am including my nav on all php pages as such:

```
<?php 
    require "nav.php"; 
    $thisPage = "pagesName";
?>
```

I am attempting to utilize the $thisPage="" (for all pages) to help with routing in the nav page:

```
<?php
  if ($thisPage=="indexPage") {
      echo '    
        <li><a href="views/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="views/testing.php">Testing Centers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><img src="images/global.png"></li>';
  } else {           //every other page already in the views folder
      echo '    
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="testing.php">Testing Centers</a></li>
        <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><img src="../images/global.png"></li> ';
  }
?>
```

The nav loads correctly for index, however, none of the links/imgs work, all links give  "Object not found! Error 404". Using the console, I know the if($thisPage=="index"){} is entered, but still no links are working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add `/` at the start of all your links and it will reference them from the root directory. That way you do not need to have separate logic for index page and other pages.

Comment: In the beginning, I was attempting to use the full route: "/views/testing.php" but it still does not work. I'm not sure why either, if you have any ideas. I have also tried to get the full path: "/Users/xampp/.....testing.php" but that would only work on my computer.